# Printing URLConnection request before sending

Tags: java, urlconnection

Java's URLConnection lets us form http requests. After forming a simple POST request like so:

```
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
con.addRequestProperty("User-agent", "Mozilla");
con.setDoOutput(true);
String data = "text to send";
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
```

Is there any way of checking what this request looks like before sending it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable [logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html) and in your logging.properties file you should have following property set

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINEST
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.level=ALL
```

And, set the property file as a JVM property

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
```